# Grabbing each of the ul children of a class, and using a jquery plugin on them

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I've got the following code in jQuery - I am trying to use the columnizer plugin.

Would this be the correct form for jQuery? I am trying to select all ul children of `.alpha_list` (which is under `#content` and `.specialties_home`) and organize the `<li>` elements into four separate columns.

Here's my code:

```
$(".specialties_home #content .alpha_list").children("ul").columnize({
    columns: 4
})
```

Comment: How would we know without seeing the HTML?

Comment: You probably only need `#content .alpha_list` as `#content` won't be anywhere else. jQuery searches for id's faster too. The rest seems fine, although I haven't used columnize.

Comment: While I've posted an answer, to try and help a little, I'm also voting to close because of the lack of information and, honestly, you could have just tried this and, when/if it *didn't* work asked a specific question about why (describing any problems, and supplying any errors you encounter).

Comment: What is your question? Is your code already working and you want a more efficient way of doing the same thing?

Answer (score 1):

try this:

> ```
> $(".specialties_home #content .alpha_list").find("ul").columnize({
>     columns: 4
> })
> ```

but of course the hierarchy of the elements must be like this then:

> ```
>     <element class="specialties_home">
>         <element id="content">
>             <element class="alpha_list">
>                 <ul><!-- list --></ul>
>                 <ul><!-- list --></ul>
>                 <ul><!-- list --></ul>
>             <ul><!-- list --></ul>
>             </element>
>         </element>
>     </element>
> ```

Comment: Can there be nothing in between the various <ul> elements?

Comment: of course there can be, that's is where your <li> elements should be put up. I just shortcut it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest, given that an `id` is specific all by itself:

```
$('#content .alpha_list ul').columnize(/*...*/);
```

If you want to apply the plug-in to *all* `ul` descendants, otherwise your posted attempt looks fine in concept, but this is hardly conclusive without seeing your HTML.

Answer (score 0):

That should work. You can also write:

```
$(".specialties_home #content .alpha_list > ul").columnize({
    columns: 4
});
```

[`X > Y`](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/) is the selector syntax for `Y` children of `X`.

Comment: That's what I said. This is just another way to write the same thing.

Comment: True, but using `querySelectorAll()` is (probably) faster than finding the selection and then calling `find()` (though I can't be bothered to JS Perf it).

Comment: @Barmar I guess you are right and the OP probably just wanted a different approach for doing the exact same thing. Remove the `.specialties_home` unecessary part and I will be able to remove my downvote ;)

Comment: @plalx For all we know, this code is used in a function that might be used on different pages, some of which have `#content` under `.specialties_home`, others don't. And he only wants to columnize the former.

Comment: @Barmar Well it could also be that the OP just doesn't know it's not necessary, but yeah I agree that since we do not know it's probably better to keep it. However SO is not so mind-changing friendly so I've made a small edit to be able to remove my downvote.